# Grid from list of Strings

Tags: vaadin

I use vaadin 23 and want to create a grid from a string list.
In the documentation I only find example with "proper" classes.
This is what I tried:

```
    Grid<String> resultList = new Grid<>();
    resultList.addColumn(string -> string).setHeader("Values");
    resultList.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_COMPACT);
    resultList.setSizeFull();
    resultList.setMaxHeight("20em");
    return resultList;
```

Th list is filled with setItems and a set of strings. This should be possible,
but nothing shows up there. If I use a list box everything works as expected, but
I want to use a grid in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your example and this works:

```
@PageTitle("Hello World")
@Route(value = "hello", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class HelloWorldView extends HorizontalLayout {

    public HelloWorldView() {
        setHeightFull();

        Grid<String> resultList = new Grid<>();
        resultList.addColumn(string -> string).setHeader("Values");
        resultList.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_COMPACT);
        resultList.setSizeFull();
        resultList.setMaxHeight("20em");

        resultList.setItems("A", "B", "C");

        add(resultList);
    }

}
```

I assume that the component where you add the Grid has no height.

Comment: Ok, If I remove the setSizeFull it is working. The table is in a vertical layout within a tab sheet.